# How to print elements/values in console which have same class name (human-readable)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have used this:

```
String GDP = driver.findElement(By.className("human-readable")).getText(); 
System.out.println(GDP);
```

...to print one. What should I do for other one?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `List <WebElement>` to access all similar elements :

```
List<WebElement> listElement = driver.findElements(By.className("human-readable"));
for(int i =0;i<listElement.size();i++) {
 String elementText = listElement.get(i).getText(); 
 System.out.println(elementText); 
}
```

Comment: @SabaMalik glad it does :)

Comment: One more thing right now I want to print two values like GDP and Population not all with "human-readable"

Comment: @SabaMalik : sorry couldn't get that, also please use another thread to ask any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS selector instead.
Below is the sample of cssSelector using Id. 
For the class I guess you can use [class='human-readable'].

```
String cssSelRefreshBtn="[id='refreshBtn']"; 
List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelRefreshBtn)) ;
for(WebElement item:a)
{
    String b= item.getText();
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rudy this code also work but I need to print two values at that since It's printing three values.

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to three values...you should show us the input and expected output. But like null pointer says, you should either elaborate it since the beginning or create another question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below:

```
Point p = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-link-accountList\"]/span[1]")).getLocation();
int xCord = p.getX();
int yCord = p.getY();
System.out.println("The Position of UserName is "+ xCord +","+yCord +" pixels");
```